# What's wrong with this RegExp?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I believe I did nothing wrong with this:

```
sed -e "s_//[01]\.thumbs\.4chan\.org/[a-z0-9]\+/src/\([0-9]\*\)s\.jpg_/${LOC}/\1s.jpg_g" -e "s_//images\.4chan\.org/[a-z0-9]\+/src/\([0-9]\*\)\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\)_/${LOC}/\1.\2_g" $LOC.html > a
```

Can someone tell me why it doesn't convert online links to offline links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `\*` and `\+` should be `*` and `+`?  Otherwise it looks literally for `*` and `+`.

Comment: Strange, because `LOC` looks like this `LOC=$(echo "$1" | sed 's_.\+/res/\([0-9]\+\)_\1_g' )` and you as can see the `+` is escaped and it works

Comment: Only the asterisk needed to be unescaped
`\*` to `*` and `\+` is good as it is
Anyway, thank you

Comment: @user1263513:  I have no doubt you are correct.  Between `vim`, PHP's `pcre`, and `grep`, I have to experiment a bit to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` in simple regex mode, as you are,  the `+` must be escaped to `\+`, as you have done, and as "expected" the asterisk `*` needs to be asis,  ie. not escaped. here are a couple of tests, using `\+` and `*`

If you want to simplify things use of `sed` in `extended regex` mode, by using the `-r` option. You won't need to escape `+`, `(`, `)`....

```
echo '//0.thumbs.4chan.org/abc123/src/029s.jpg' |
    sed -n "\_//[01]\.thumbs\.4chan\.org/[a-z0-9]\+/src/\([0-9]*\)s\.jpg_p"

echo '//images.4chan.org/abc123/src/029.jpg' |
    sed -n "\_//images\.4chan\.org/[a-z0-9]\+/src/\([0-9]*\)\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\)_p"
```

output:

```
//0.thumbs.4chan.org/abc123/src/029s.jpg
//images.4chan.org/abc123/src/029.jpg
```